# Linking additional dependencies with XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I'm trying to compile a game I made with  the Allegro library. The library has .a files which I need to tell XCode to use because right now my code has no errors but it as unreferenced function errors which means it needs the .a files to do the static linking. How do I provide these to XCode? (sort of like the XCode equivalent of MSVC's additional dependencies Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the .a files to your project in the same way that you would add source files and everything should just work.